# Proper Way To Link to Other Magento Pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am trying to link to Login page, but my link is only redirecting to my home page. Here is what I am trying.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $block = $objectManagerLinks->get('\Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Header');
```

In my div

```
echo __('<b><a href="%1" class="headlink">LOGIN</a></b>', $block->getLoginLink());
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you

```
<?php echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>
```

Comment: Magento2 for the win!